# How to include objects into mod.rs in rust?

Tags: module, rust, rust-cargo

Since the documentation on that is a bit vast, I wanted just to tackle a single problem with modules

I have the following files

```
project/src/main.rs
project/src/win/mod.rs  //just some win32 specific utilities
project/src/geom/mod.rs
project/src/geom/rectangle.rs
project/src/geom/triangle.rs
```

As long as there is just the `mod.rs` (like with the folder `win`), I have no problems

- I just put inside that file the function I'm interested in `pub fn enumerate_monitors() -> Vec<MONITORINFOEXW>`
- Just need to write `mod win;` somewhere
- Then I can use the function `let monitors = win::enumerate_monitors();`

But that was a small file, so no real problems, then I'm starting to add much code inside `geom`, I can't add that all inside `mod.rs`

How can I add all shapes to `geom` module?

```
mod geom;

fn main()
{
   let tri  = geom::triangle::new();
   let rect = geom::rectangle:new();
}
```

Is it also possible to keep a `mod.rs` inside the `geom` folder in order to use that to expose all shapes?

Comment: Stylistic note. `mod.rs` is "old" Rust (2015 edition); modern Rust (2018 edition) idiomatic style is to use `src/geom.rs` and `src/geom/rectangle.rs`, in which case the hierarchy is `crate::geom` and `crate::geom::rectangle`.

Comment: So cluttering main folder with an additional file per folder, instead of cluttering each folder with an additional file ? Mmmm I was doing a similar thing with C++ forwward declarations..

Comment: I think it's more than people were complaining about all the `mod.rs` files everywhere -- in some editors, it's hard to distinguish which `mod.rs` is which from the tab name. It also has a better evolution path: start with `x.rs`, and when it grows too big add `x/...` with bits of functionality.

Comment: sure I'll stick with more recent best practices:) these are always for good, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's a library you are looking to create (and not an executable crate) there must be at least a `src/lib.rs` file. That file most times has no `main()` and it's usual to "import" the various sub-modules  in there.

In your case, you could bring in scope other modules with something like this:

```rust
// For example in project/src/geom/mod.rs
// bring rectangle and triangle in the scope of the current module:

pub mod rectangle;
pub mod triangle;
```

After this whatever other file `use`s geom/mod.rs also has access to functions / structs defined in `rectangle.rs` and can access them using something like `rectangle::<struct-or-function-name`

Additionally, you can also use something like `pub use self::rectangle::*`:

```rust
pub mod rectangle;
pub mod triangle;

use self::rectangle::*;
use self::triangle::*;
```

This brings all the functions / structs etc. in the scope of `geom/mod.rs`. This way whatever other module uses `geom/mod.rs` won't have to specify e.g., the extra `rectangle::` scope before accessing its structs and functions.

Comment: thank you, I'm not creating a library, I'm just exploring the build system, the language, cmake and c compiler interactions. I'm very grateful to you for your post that's exactly what I was searching for.